# Error with String endIndex in Swift

Tags: swift, swift4

I have the following code:

```
let hello = "Hola"
let indexI = hello.startIndex
let indexF = hello.endIndex
hello[indexI] // "H"
hello[hello.startIndex] // H
hello[hello.index(after: indexI)] // o

hello[indexF] // Fatal error: Can't form a Character from an empty String
```

But I have an error in  `hello[indexF]`Why?

Comment: In Xcode, if you option-click on `endindex` it says *A string’s “past the end” position—that is, the position one greater than the last valid subscript argument.*

Comment: Perfectly understood... thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to access the last element you need to replace:

```
let indexF = hello.endIndex
```

With:

```
let indexF = hello.index(before: hello.endIndex)
```

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1539571-endindex) of `endIndex` says:

> A string’s “past the end” position—that is, the position one greater
>   than the last valid subscript argument.